# Typescript strict boolean expression error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

While creating conditional classes with the following lines of code:

```
className={({ selected }) =>
    classNames(
        selected
            ? 'bg-gray-100 text-gray-900'
            : 'text-gray-600 hover:bg-gray-50 hover:text-gray-900',
        'group flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-base font-medium rounded-md'
    )
}
```

But I keep getting a `Type '({ selected }: { selected: any; }) => string' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)` error.

I have tried explicitly adding an `any` type but it didn't work.

Because I also integrated `eslint` to my project, I even tried adding a `eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/strict-boolean-expressions` rule just above the `selected` parameter, all to no avail.

Please can anyone figure out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're passing to the `className` prop is actually a function that takes a single argument, and then calls `classNames` to return a string. That's where this type is coming from:

```
({ selected }: { selected: any; }) => string
```

What you probably want to do instead is this (assuming that `selected` exists in scope):

```
className={
    classNames(
        selected
            ? 'bg-gray-100 text-gray-900'
            : 'text-gray-600 hover:bg-gray-50 hover:text-gray-900',
        'group flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-base font-medium rounded-md'
    )
}
```

That will set the `className` prop to the result of calling `classNames`, which is what you want - a `string`.